# Repeat the number conversion of the user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to repeat a certain amount of print that prints out "Conversion #1"
but goes up base on the user input, so if the user enters that they want 3 different conversions it'll be:

> Conversion#1
>
> code....
>
> Conversion#2
>
> code...
>
> Conversion#3
>
> code...

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    public class TempConverter {

        public static void main(String[] args){


            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.0");
            System.out.println("Temperature Converter");
            System.out.println("---------------------");

             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

               //this is the conversion promt
              System.out.print("How many conversions would you like to make: ");
              int conversions=input.nextInt();
              for(int i = 0; i < conversions; i++);
              System.out.println("Conversion # " + i++);
             
              System.out.println ("To convert from celsius to fahrenheit type 1 ");
              System.out.print ("To convert from fahrenheit to celsius type 2: ");
              int choice=input.nextInt();


                System.out.print ("Enter temperature: ");
              double temp=input.nextDouble();
              double result=tempChanger(choice,temp);
                if (choice == 1)
                     System.out.println ("The conversion of "+temp+" from celcius to fahrenheit is "+df.format(result) );
                else if (choice == 2)
                     System.out.println ("The conversion of "+temp+" from fahrenheit to celcius is "+df.format(result) );
                else
                     System.out.println ("Not a valid choice, try agiain");




            }

            public static double tempChanger(int choice, double temp)
            {

             double converted=0.0;
            if (choice == 1)
                   converted=9.0/5.0*temp+32;
              else
                  converted=5.0/9.0*(temp -32);

              return converted;
              }
            }
```

Comment: You've printed requirements and code, but no explanation -- what's not working? what don't you understand? what's your specific question?

Comment: looks like you are missing the {}  after your for loop.

Comment: it'll ask the user for how many conversion numbers but when I run the code it just ignores the conversion question.

Answer (score -1):

as per my best understanding you want to allow user to choose type of conversion everytime before entering temprature value

your code looks fine but  following line should be changed  to run the loop for value of variable conversions time.

```
 System.out.println("Conversion # " + i++);

to 
 System.out.println("Conversion # " + i+1);


also
```

for(int i = 0; i < conversions; i++); should be changed to 
    (int i = 0; i < conversions; i+1){ 
    and put closing bracket after 
    System.out.println ("Not a valid choice, try agiain");

following is perfect code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    public class TempConverter {

        public static void main(String[] args){


            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.0");
            System.out.println("Temperature Converter");
            System.out.println("---------------------");

             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

               //this is the conversion promt
              System.out.print("How many conversions would you like to make: ");
              int conversions=input.nextInt();
              for(int i = 0; i < conversions; i++){
              System.out.println("Conversion # " + i++);

              System.out.println ("To convert from celsius to fahrenheit type 1 ");
              System.out.print ("To convert from fahrenheit to celsius type 2: ");
              int choice=input.nextInt();


                System.out.print ("Enter temperature: ");
              double temp=input.nextDouble();
              double result=tempChanger(choice,temp);
                if (choice == 1)
                     System.out.println ("The conversion of "+temp+" from celcius to fahrenheit is "+df.format(result) );
                else if (choice == 2)
                     System.out.println ("The conversion of "+temp+" from fahrenheit to celcius is "+df.format(result) );
                else
                     System.out.println ("Not a valid choice, try agiain");

        }


            }

            public static double tempChanger(int choice, double temp)
            {

             double converted=0.0;
            if (choice == 1)
                   converted=9.0/5.0*temp+32;
              else
                  converted=5.0/9.0*(temp -32);

              return converted;
              }
            }
```

Comment: when I change it to that it says cannot find symbol and points at the i

Comment: it is logical even though it might give you compilation errors. putting  i++ statement within println will increase the value of i two times for every loop.

Comment: when I run the program it'll out put the number I put in conversions instead of Conversion #1.... it outputs 3.

Comment: that works except how do I make it go up by one it keeps going up by 2 or 10